# Terraform: How to enable deletion of batch service compute environment?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I have stood up infrastructure using Terraform, including a batch service job queue, compute environment, and job definition.

After making changes to the Terraform I have run `terraform apply` and get the following error:

```
Error: error deleting Batch Compute Environment (data-load): : Cannot delete, found existing JobQueue relationship
    status code: 400, request id: 25449415-9c36-4748-95e6-925647bd716a
```

There are no jobs in the job queue. I assumed it would be removed/replaced along with other resources associated with the batch service rather than holding up the show for the compute environment as it's being replaced.

In the past, the only way I could get past this was to nuke my state file and start afresh, but I assume there must be a better way. How can I get past this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a resource is recreated in Terraform, it will be deleted and created in order by default. So if compute_environment_nameyou change and apply only, the computing environment on which the job queue depends temporarily does not exist, so you will die as follows.
Error: Error applying plan:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_batch_compute_environment.sample (destroy): 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_batch_compute_environment.sample: error deleting Batch Compute Environment (sample): : Cannot delete, found existing JobQueue relationship
```

Therefore, compute_environment_namechange create_before_destroy = trueand specify the lifecycle explicitly.

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "sample" {
  compute_environment_name = "sample-v2"
                     ...
    instance_type = [
      "m5",
    ]
                     ...
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Could somebody use this lifecycle value without getting `Error: : Object already exists status code: 409, request id: 324ff32e-c897-4ccc-86fc-77471b3c8f6d` when trying to `terraform apply` changes to the compute environment?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding the create_before_destroy lifecycle setting and using compute_environment_name_**prefix** instead of a constant compute_environment_name. As below:

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "sample" {
  compute_environment_name_prefix = var.compute_env_name

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  compute_resources {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: As of October 2022, this is the solution to avoid both "Object already exists" and "Found existing JobQueue" errors